# expression 2 uav script

Tags: jvm-languages

How do I make an expression2 script for a drone that orbits the map without hitting walls and then home in onto a target after a target (player name) has been set by typing a command into the chat

I tried with this but eneded up hitting into walls and I need help on the homing part  so..I'll need an e2 chip that makes a drone orbits a map until a target has been set via command written into the chat box after that the drone will home in onto said target

```
@inputs EGP:wirelink
@persist [UAV]:entity
@persist [AngPull Speed RngLength]:number
@persist RotAng:angle
@persist [Positions]:table
```

```
interval(10)

if(first()){

    AngPull = 1
    Speed = 2 #Multiplier
    RngLength = 8000
    
    #EGP = spawnEgp("models/hunter/plates/plate2x2.mdl",entity():pos(),ang(),1):wirelink()

    propSpawnUndo(0)
    if(EGP){
        entity():setPos(entity():toWorld(vec(0,0,-10)))
    }
    UAV = propSpawn("models/xqm/jetbody3_s2.mdl",entity():toWorld(vec(0,0,30)),entity():angles(),0)
    UAV:setColor(vec(randint(40,100)))
    UAV:propGravity(0)
    
    UAV:setTrails(30,30,1,"trails/smoke",vec(100),255)
    
    rangerPersist(1)
    rangerFilter(UAV)
    
    RotAng = ang()
    
    UAV:soundPlay(1,inf(),"Phx.HoverLight")
    
    noCollideAll(UAV,1)#so we dont kill players

}

if(owner():keyZoom()){UAV:propFreeze(0)}

if(changed(EGP)){
    if(EGP){
        entity():setPos(entity():toWorld(vec(0,0,-10)))
    }else{
        entity():setPos(entity():toWorld(vec(0,0,10)))
    }
}

Ranger = rangerOffset(RngLength,UAV:pos(),UAV:right())
Height = abs(-11519.968750 - UAV:pos()[3])

if(Ranger:hit()){RotAng+=ang(1,1*((RngLength-Ranger:distance())/(RngLength)),0),Mul=((RngLength-Ranger:distance())/(RngLength/150))*Speed}else{Mul=20*Speed}

if(Height<1500){RotAng+=ang(0,0,-1)}else{RotAng = RotAng:setRoll(0)}

timer("soundplay",5000)

soundPitch(1,UAV:vel():length())

UAV:applyForce(UAV:right()*UAV:mass()*Mul - UAV:vel())
UAV:applyTorque( ( ( (UAV:toLocalAxis(rotationVector(quat( RotAng )/quat(UAV)))) *200-UAV:angVelVector()*20)*UAV:inertia() ) *AngPull)

foreach(Key,Ply:entity = players()){
    
    local Ranger = rangerOffset(100000,UAV:pos(),Ply:pos()-UAV:pos())
    if(Ranger:entity() == Ply){
        Positions[Ply:steamID(),vector] = Ply:pos()
        
        EGP:egpBox(Key,vec2(clamp(Ply:pos()[1]/50+200,0,500), clamp(Ply:pos()[2]/50+200,0,500) ),vec2(7.5))
        EGP:egpColor(Key,teamColor(Ply:team()))
        EGP:egpTextLayout(Key+20,Ply:name(),vec2(clamp(Ply:pos()[1]/50+200,0,500), clamp(Ply:pos()[2]/50+200,0,500) ),vec2(100,50))
        EGP:egpFont(Key+20,"",12)
    }

}

if(changed(UAV)){
    if(!UAV){
        selfDestructAll()
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not Java

Comment: Its golo but golo tag doesnt exist here